# NodeJS / ExpressJS: Syntax error unexpected end of file

Tags: node.js, express, pm2, typescript1.7

One of my NodeJS / ExpressJS app gets quite from time to time by the error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at parse (native)
```

Unfortunately there is no line number and no stack. The hole project is based on typescript and compiles just fine. The process is running on a PM2.

Any idea how to hunt down this error?

Regards and thx...

Comment: Also this is a fantastic debugger
https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector

Answer (score -1):

Search your app source code for `JSON.parse`, then find if any of the input your are getting is a proper JSON. I suspect you are getting HTML page as a response for one of your requests (due to `404` or `5xx`)
To track down the error:

```js
try{
   JSON.parse(body);
}
catch(err){
  console.log('error due to ', err);
}
```

Comment: All json.parse are located in try catches. I think it could be a 3rd party npm module... but how to track it down, with no trace?